# Is there a shortcut for selecting the suggested user when tagging in a comment?

Tags: support, keyboard-shortcuts

What's the shortcut to select the current suggested user when tagging hir in a comment?

Comment: Yep, [*hir* is official](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hir#Pronoun).